# Getting Memory allocation problem at UIBarButtonItem in Iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

Here I am getting memory allocation problem at UIBarButtonItem and the related code for that is:

```
  toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
  toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
  [toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 350,320,20)];
  [self.view addSubview:toolbar];

  UIBarButtonItem* barItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:@selector(categoryConfig:)]  ;

  rightBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(dialogOtherAction:)]  ;

  UIBarButtonItem* barItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:@selector(categoryConfig:)]  ;

  NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: barItem1,rightBarItem,barItem2, nil];

  [barItem1 release];
  [barItem2 release];
  [rightBarItem release];
  [toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
```

after adding UIBarButtonItems into the array items I released them.even though its showing allocations at barbuttons.

can any help me for this?

Thank you,
Monish.

Comment: Please clarify the problem you are having. Is it a memory leak? If so, what is being blamed, both barItems or just one?

Comment: No its a memory allocation problem not a leak.both BarItems are blamed.

Comment: what's a "memory allocation problem"? You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocated `toolbar` with `toolbar = [UIToolbar new];`, so you need to release it.